# How to find eigenvalues for the following ode?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the following Sturm-Liouville problem,
$$(\sqrt{\sin \theta} Y')' + \lambda \sqrt{\sin \theta} Y =0$$
where $Y(\theta):[0,\pi] \to \mathbb{R}$ with boundary conditions $Y'(0)=Y'(\pi)=0.$

I used maple and got the following explicit solution,
$$Y(\theta) = \sin(\theta)^{1/4} \left(P^\mu_{\nu}(\cos \theta) + Q^{\mu}_{\nu}(\cos \theta)\right)$$
where $\mu=1/4$ and $\nu = \frac{\sqrt{16\lambda+1}}{4}-\frac{1}{2}.$ When I try to differentiate this expression and plug in the boundary conditions, I get division by zero error. What other ways can I use to compute the eigenvalue of this expression?

Answer (score 1):

Given a general solution of the form $f=c_1 f_1 + c_2 f_2$, your BCs say $c_1 f_1'(0) + c_2 f_2'(0)=0,c_1 f_1'(\pi)+c_2 f_2'(\pi)=0$. You have an eigenvalue when this has a nontrivial solution, which means that $f_0'(0) f_1'(\pi)=f_0'(\pi) f_1'(0)$. You need to solve this algebraic equation for $\lambda$ to find the eigenvalues.

Comment: The problem here is that the derivative at those points is not defined, perhaps there are other ways to approach this issue?

Comment: @nls Then the problem itself doesn't make sense strongly anyway and you need to pass to the weak formulation.

Comment: @nls Either that or there is some possibility for "catastrophic cancellation" in the singularities in the two basis elements. If this is the case then you've chosen inconvenient basis elements; this is a thing in the context of Bessel functions for example (where something like $Y_n+J_n,Y_n-J_n$ is mathematically a valid basis but creates similar analytical problems). Try examining their asymptotic behavior near the endpoints to see if some basis rearrangement can be scavenged.